# Any way to compute match count for each SOLR query clause?

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to be able to know how many times a particular query clause matches text in a field.  For example, if I had something like:

q="Short Phrase" || term

and I configured analyzer such that it could match field text such as:

short phrase term
short phrases

I would like to return how many times each query clause (i.e, "Short Phrase" and "term") actually matched something in a field (so, if it was just the example text, the "match count" for "Short Phrase" would be 2 and for "term" would be 1)

I took a look at the QueryParser API to see if there was something obvious I could override to accumulate this data, but its architecture is not easy to divine.  So if anyone has any experience doing this sort of thing, I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098083/term-vector-frequency-in-lucene-4-0
I think this should help

Comment: This works fine for individual terms (there is also a query function, termfreq, available for this same purpose), but it does not work for phrases. What I would really like is to know when a particular phrase query matches and to accumulate a hit count for that. I have looked at the PhraseQuery/PhraseWeight source code, and it appears that inserting some strategic code to accumulate the phrase hits would be possible, but I am loathe to create a custom version of SOLR just for this purpose.  But since I am quite new to SOLR, I was hoping I might have overlooked a less drastic solution.