# OR terms query with boosting

Tags: lucene

Using Lucene, I want to compare a document in the index with the rest of documents. I found out that an [easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844194/get-cosine-similarity-between-two-documents-in-lucene) would be to submit the document as a query. The problem is that I need to put terms as an OR-Ring and, the most difficult part, boost the terms with the `term frequency`.

I think that if I trim all blank spaces of the document and replace them with `' OR '`, lucene will parse it and interpret it. But is there a most sophisticated way to deal with this problem?

And which is the easiest way to boost the terms with their respective frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to re-implement Lucene's [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html).

Comment: In fact I think that I need something simpler than that. I just want to compare two documents using the tf*idf scheme, i.e., I want to get high scores if these documents share very infrequent terms.